# how to make a new column based on comparing two dataframes' unique id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, series

[image: Data]

Hi, I have two dataframes which have OrderID and stage numbers. I want to create a new column for August Dataframe which returns values in July's stage number if the orderID matches. If not, please return "N/A".

How should I use lambda and apply functions to create this column? (don't use join...)

Any clues and suggestions will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use `lambda` and `apply`? there are more efficient ways to do this (either using `merge` or `map`, or `join`, although you specifically say you don't want that...). Also, please post your dataframes as text so we can cut and paste them, rather than re-creating them ourselves.

Comment: It is an assignment. apply would be inefficient in this case. Why not use join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with a series. Note if you have `NaN` values your series will be forced to `float` as `NaN` is a float value. This is unavoidable without adding inefficiencies.

```
aug = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555], 'Prior': np.nan})
jul = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777], 'Stage': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

aug['Prior'] = aug['ID'].map(jul.set_index('ID')['Stage'])

print(aug)

    ID  Prior
0  111    NaN
1  222    1.0
2  333    2.0
3  444    3.0
4  555    4.0
```

A more long-winded solution is possible via `pd.Series.update` and aligning indices:

```
aug.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
aug['Prior'].update(jul.set_index('ID')['Stage'])
aug = aug.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Although I hate posting this as an answer but if you are still interested in using lambda and apply you can you as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Order_id_July':[222,333,444,555,666,777],'stage':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Order_id_August':[111,222,333,444,555]})
```

Mapper function(similar to lookup)

```
def myfunc(row):
    if set([row[0]]).intersection(set(df.Order_id_July)):       
        return int(df[df.Order_id_July==row[0]]['stage'])
    return np.nan

df2['prior_stage']=df2.apply(lambda x:myfunc(x),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Order_id_August prior_stage
    111         NaN
    222         1.0
    333         2.0
    444         3.0
    555         4.0
```

If later you change your mind and want to explore better ways to achieving this task try below code

```
df2.merge(df,left_on='Order_id_August',right_on='Order_id_July',how='left').drop('Order_id_July',axis=1)

Order_id_August prior_stage
        111         NaN
        222         1.0
        333         2.0
        444         3.0
        555         4.0
```